# How to make a sidenav fixed to an existing Sticky Header onscroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already have Sticky header nav in my project, however I need to have the sidenav (filter section) or Aside also show fixed on the left when the scroll occurs as there is a long list on the right side of the page. As I mentioned the header is already in FIXED position to top. How can I make the Aside or sidenav to stick along with the header, just beneath it. I am unable to do it via CSS and not sure how can I accomplish this using jquery.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Show me, what you have done so far!

Comment: I'm pretty sure myself and many others can answer this question for you correctly but we would need to see what you have tried first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide us with your code with the css?
Basically what you can do is:

- Create a container to have your sidebar and center section in with
  overflow hidden and width to 100%.
- Set the sidebar position as relative, with a provided width and
  padding to the top so that the navbar does not overlap on it.
- Set your main container (the element containing the list) width
  position relative, this way it will display next to the sidebar, you
  can add overflow auto to make sure that you get a scrollbar when you
  have many list items.

There are several ways to solve your problem.
You can also use an Iframe but I wouldn't recommend it for responsive designs.

Comment: Thank you Elie, I have managed to resolve it. Thanks for your help.